# Expandable property only returns count and capacity C#

Tags: c#

I want to include joint holder's details to main account holders profile multiple joint holders will be there here I use  "shareholdercolection" class derived from collectiobass class assigned joint holders details to it. At the execution of application property only returns Capacity and count. it is not called property descriptor why?

[image]

```
public class ShareholderCollection : CollectionBase, ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    public void Add( UiclsJointHolderSummary sh)
    {
        this.List.Add(sh);
    }

    public void Remove( UiclsJointHolderSummary sh)
    {
        
        this.List.Remove(sh);
    }

   
    public UiclsJointHolderSummary this[int index]
    {
        get{
            return (UiclsJointHolderSummary)this.List[index];
        }
        set
        {
            base.List[index] = (UiclsJointHolderSummary)value;
        }

    }

    public AttributeCollection GetAttributes()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(this, noCustomTypeDesc: true);
    }

    public string GetClassName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetClassName(this, true);
    }


    public string GetComponentName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetComponentName(this, true);
    }


    public TypeConverter GetConverter()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this, true);
    }


    public EventDescriptor GetDefaultEvent()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent(this, true);
    }


    public PropertyDescriptor GetDefaultProperty()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty(this, true);
    }


    public object GetEditor(System.Type editorBaseType)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(this, editorBaseType, true);
    }


    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents()
    { 
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, true);
    }
    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, attributes, true);
    }

      

     PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection pds = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(null);
         

        for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i = i + 1)
        {
            ShareholderCollectionPropertyDescriptor pd = new 
 `      `ShareholderCollectionPropertyDescriptor( this,i);

            pds.Add(pd);
        }
        return pds;
    }

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return GetProperties(attributes);

    }

    public object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd )
    {
        return this;
    }

}
```

Descriptor class

```
 public class ShareholderCollectionPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private ShareholderCollection collection;
    private int index = 1;
    public ShareholderCollectionPropertyDescriptor(ShareholderCollection _Coll,int _id) : base("#" + _id.ToString(), null)
    {

        this.collection = _Coll;
        this.index = _id;

    }

    public override AttributeCollection Attributes
    {
        get
        {
           // var attributes = TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(GetValue(null), false);
            return new AttributeCollection(null);
            //return attributes;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get => this.collection.GetType();
    }

    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            UiclsJointHolderSummary sh =  this.collection[index];
            return "[" + sh.NDX.ToString().Trim() + "] " + sh.INITIALS.ToString() + " " + sh.LASTNAME.ToString();
        }
    }

    public override string Description
    {
        get
        {
            UiclsJointHolderSummary sh = this.collection[index];
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(sh.ADDRESS.ADDRESS1);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(sh.ADDRESS.ADDRESS2);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(sh.ADDRESS.ADDRESS3);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(sh.ADDRESS.CITY);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(sh.ADDRESS.PCODE);

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }


    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return this.collection[index];
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly
    { get => false; }


    //public override string Name
    //{
    //    get { return "#" + index.ToString(); }
    //}
    public override Type PropertyType
    {
        get => this.collection[index].GetType();

    }

    

   

    public override void ResetValue(object component)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return true;
    }


    //private static string GetDisplayName(ShareholderCollection ilst, int ind )
    //{
    //    UiclsJointHolderSummary sh = ilst.Item(ind);
    //    return "[" + sh.NDX.ToString().Trim() + "] " + sh.INITIALS.ToString() + " " + sh.LASTNAME.ToString();
    //    //return str=DisplayName;
    //}

    


    
}
```

convertor class

```
public class ShareholderCollectionConverter: ExpandableObjectConverter
{
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context , CultureInfo culture , Object pvalue , Type destType )
    {
        if ((destType == typeof(string) )&& (pvalue.GetType()==typeof( ShareholderCollection)))
        {
            return "Joint Shareholders";
                
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, pvalue, destType);


    }
}
```

property class

```
ShareholderCollection JointHolder= new ShareholderCollection ();

[TypeConverter(typeof(ShareholderCollectionConverter))]
    [Category("23. Joint Members")]
    [DisplayName("10. Shareholders")]
    [Browsable(true)] 
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public ShareholderCollection JointHolders
    {
        get
        {
            return JointHolder;
          
        }
        set { JointHolder = value; }
        
    }
```

property values assigned at runtime

```
 clsJoinShareholderCollSub objJointShareholderCollSub = new clsJoinShareholderCollSub();
                        ShareholderCollection sb = objJointShareholderCollSub.getJointHolders(objUIclsFolio);
                        
                        objUIclsFolio.JointHolders = sb;
                        pgGeneralFrmFolio.SelectedObject = objUIclsFolio;
                        pgGeneralFrmFolio.Refresh();
```